# jQuery Datatable, resize col width by UI

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am deciding what jquery plug-in to use, DataTable or jqGrid.

I made a big search but can not find the answer.
Is it possible in DataTable UI to resize column width by mouse,
as it is made in jqGrid?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't let the resizable issue stop you, it's on the way:
http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/1676/x

Datatables is far and away the most featured, well written, and best supported grid solution out there, and I've probably either used or researched them all.  Just the Ajax options alone make it more powerful than its next nearest competitor.  While you're waiting for resizing, get it fully working and get all the features in that you want.

I was thinking I needed resizing too, but found with intelligent UI planning that it really wasn't at all missed.  My clients LOVE the sorting, paging, ajax load, etc, and I love the fact that it's fully integrated with ThemeRoller so I can rebrand an app in just minutes.

Answer (score 2):

I see the question is older, but as I got here just after finding my solution for that, I`m posting what I found working.

It is possible in DataTables to resize the columns with mouse with the **ColReorderWithResize** plugin.
Example and download on their site in 3rd party section:
https://datatables.net/extras/thirdparty/ColReorderWithResize/

Edit: Found in the forums is also discussed about this plugin...

Comment: The link is now http://legacy.datatables.net/extras/thirdparty/ColReorderWithResize/ since it is for the legacy Datatables (version < 1.10)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a huge fan of datatables too, but at the moment the column resizing patches are a bit flaky and incomplete, although I'm sure it's just a matter of time before it's sorted.

In the meantime, there is [flexigrid](http://flexigrid.info/) (http://flexigrid.info/).

It supports the usual (paging, filtering, etc...) but also resizing of columns (which is implemented very nicely).

However, unlike datatables it hasn't got the support base or developer community backing, and changes are pretty infrequent. If that doesn't matter for you, it could be the way to go.

Hope this helps!